# Detect non Latin characters with regex Pattern in Java

Tags: java, regex, latin

I THINK Latin characters are what I mean in my question, but I'm not entirely sure what the correct classification is. I'm trying to use a regex Pattern to test if a string contains non Latin characters. I'm expecting the following results

```
"abcDE 123";  // Yes, this should match
"!@#$%^&*";   // Yes, this should match
"aaàààäää";   // Yes, this should match
"ベビードラ";   // No, this shouldn't match
"";  // No, this shouldn't match
```

My understanding is that the built-in `{IsLatin}` preset simply detects if any of the characters are Latin. I want to detect if any characters are not Latin.

```
Pattern LatinPattern = Pattern.compile("\\p{IsLatin}");
Matcher matcher = LatinPattern.matcher(str);
if (!matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("is NON latin");
    return;
}
System.out.println("is latin");
```

Comment: I think you actually want to check if a string is ASCII, `Pattern LatinPattern = Pattern.compile("\\p{ASCII}");`. See https://ideone.com/FeTIiT

Comment: Yeah, maybe ASCII is what I mean. The pattern you posted tests if any characters are ASCII. I'm interested in detecting if any characters are non ASCII.

Comment: The question contradicts itself. It says that `"abcDE 123"` should match, but then complains that `\p{IsLatin}` matches and says you "want to detect if any characters are not Latin". So which is it? Do you want the regex to match or not to match, when string contains non-latin characters? Please **edit** the question and clarify what result you expect from the regex.

Comment: *FYI:* `\p{IsLatin}` matches Latin characters. The reverse test `\P{IsLatin}`, using uppercase `P`, matches anything that `\p{IsLatin}` doesn't, i.e. all non-Latin characters. `\P{IsLatin}` is the same as `[^\p{IsLatin}]`.

Comment: I'm expecting the regex to match if all characters are Latin characters, and to not match if any characters are non Latin characters. Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*TL;DR:* Use regex `^[\p{Print}\p{IsLatin}]*$`

---

You want a regex that matches if the string consists of:

- Spaces
- Digits
- Punctuation
- Latin characters (Unicode script "Latin")

Easiest way is to combine `\p{IsLatin}` with `\p{Print}`, where `Pattern` defines `\p{Print}` as:

- `\p{Print}` - A printable character: `[\p{Graph}\x20]`

  - `\p{Graph}` - A visible character: `[\p{Alnum}\p{Punct}]`

    - `\p{Alnum}` - An alphanumeric character: `[\p{Alpha}\p{Digit}]`

      - `\p{Alpha}` - An alphabetic character: `[\p{Lower}\p{Upper}]`

        - `\p{Lower}` - A lower-case alphabetic character: **`[a-z]`**
        - `\p{Upper}` - An upper-case alphabetic character: **`[A-Z]`**
      - `\p{Digit}` - A decimal digit: **`[0-9]`**
    - `\p{Punct}` - Punctuation: One of **`` !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~ ``**
  - `\x20` - A space:

Which makes `\p{Print}` the same as `[\p{ASCII}&&\P{Cntrl}]`, i.e. ASCII characters that are not control characters.

The `\p{Alpha}` part overlaps with `\p{IsLatin}`, but that's fine, since the character class eliminates duplicates.

So, regex is: **`^[\p{Print}\p{IsLatin}]*$`**

*Test*

```java
Pattern latinPattern = Pattern.compile("^[\\p{Print}\\p{IsLatin}]*$");

String[] inputs = { "abcDE 123", "!@#$%^&*", "aaàààäää", "ベビードラ", "" };
for (String input : inputs) {
    System.out.print("\"" + input + "\": ");
    Matcher matcher = latinPattern.matcher(input);
    if (! matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("is NON latin");
    } else {
        System.out.println("is latin");
    }
}
```

*Output*

```
"abcDE 123": is latin
"!@#$%^&*": is latin
"aaàààäää": is latin
"ベビードラ": is NON latin
"": is NON latin
```

Comment: wait...you sure the emojis are non latin? Seriously, this answer is beautiful.

Comment: @aran Yeah, I'm sure, and both OP and the Unicode "script" property agrees too. 

Comment: @aran  "Input Symbol For Latin Capital Letters" ([U+1F520](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+1F520)) is not a ["Latin" Script](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/scripts/Latn) character.

Answer (score 2):

All [Latin Unicode character classes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop) are:

```
\p{InBasic_Latin}: U+0000–U+007F
\p{InLatin-1_Supplement}: U+0080–U+00FF
\p{InLatin_Extended-A}: U+0100–U+017F
\p{InLatin_Extended-B}: U+0180–U+024F
```

So, the answer is either

```java
Pattern LatinPattern = Pattern.compile("^[\\p{InBasicLatin}\\p{InLatin-1Supplement}\\p{InLatinExtended-A}\\p{InLatinExtended-B}]+$");
Pattern LatinPattern = Pattern.compile("^[\\x00-\\x{024F}]+$"); //U+0000-U+024F
```

Note that underscores are removed from the Unicode property class names in Java.

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/oknsCe):

```java
List<String> strs = Arrays.asList(
        "abcDE 123",  // Yes, this should match
        "!@#$%^&*",   // Yes, this should match
        "aaàààäää",   // Yes, this should match
        "ベビードラ", // No, this shouldn't match
        "");     // No, this shouldn't match  
Pattern LatinPattern = Pattern.compile("^[\\p{InBasicLatin}\\p{InLatin-1Supplement}\\p{InLatinExtended-A}\\p{InLatinExtended-B}]+$");
//Pattern LatinPattern = Pattern.compile("^[\\x00-\\x{024F}]+$"); //U+0000-U+024F
for (String str : strs) {
    Matcher matcher = LatinPattern.matcher(str);
    if (!matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(str + " => is NON Latin");
        //return;
    } else {
        System.out.println(str + " => is Latin");
    }
}
```

Note: if you replace `.find()` with `.matches()`, you can throw away `^` and `$` in the pattern.

Output:

```java
abcDE 123 => is Latin
!@#$%^&* => is Latin
aaàààäää => is Latin
ベビードラ => is NON Latin
 => is NON Latin
```